# Match items with specific text JavaScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to modify already existing web application, while I was debugging the project it seemed that this particular method bellow is filtering results depending on the text input it's like a search box, I was trying to figure out what is happening in this JS method but I had no luck since I am a Javascript beginner, would anybody explain how this works?

```
function FilterResult() {
ShowLoader();
var features = '';
$("input:checkbox[name='feature']:checkbox:checked").each(function (i) {
    //features[i] = $(this).val();
    features += (features.length > 0 ? ',' : '') + $(this).attr('data-attributeid') + '|' + $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to show a loading image or something (ShowLoader()), then it is initializing the variable features with an empty string:

`var features = '';`

It then walks through all checkboxes with the name attribute "feature", that is checked (like 'input type="checkbox" name="feature" checked="checked"'):

```
$("input:checkbox[name='feature']:checkbox:checked").each(function (i) {
```

It then adds a comma, if features variable is not empty (length > 0), then attaches the content of javascript attribute "data-attributeid", followed by a pipe ("|") character, then followed by the value of the checkbox.

```
    features += (features.length > 0 ? ',' : '') + $(this).attr('data-attributeid') + '|' + $(this).val();
```

You will then have something like

```
"123|value1,456|value2,789|value3"
```

in your features variable if you have the following checkboxes on your page:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="feature" checked="checked" data-attributeid="123" value="value1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="feature" checked="checked" data-attributeid="456" value="value2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="feature" checked="checked" data-attributeid="789" value="value3" />
```